# bot composer - publish to Azure - Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0

Tags: azure-bot-service, bot-framework-composer

trying to publish my bot to azure via composer. Already got Azure resource group and Web App Bot created. When I try to publish selected profile in composer i get this error:

Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0

My configuration:

```
{
"accessToken": "<My Token>",
"hostname": "<My web app bot name>",  
"settings": {
    "MicrosoftAppId": "<app id>",
    "MicrosoftAppPassword": "<app password>"
     }
}
```

Trying to follow this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-publish-bot#deploy-bot-to-azure

Not sure if problem is in syntax or in Azure.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: If you have MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword then write in your configuration above. Otherwise make it empty string and then check.

Comment: Hi, when write only MicrosoftAppID and MicrosoftAppPassword i get this error - Required field `accessToken` is missing from publishing profile. Whne I add accessToken I get 
Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0

Comment: You need to create accesstoken within Azure portal. Check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?tabs=dotnet .. Within that see this topic: Grant your registered app permissions to Azure Storage. Use the generated Application(Client ID) as accessToken in your above JSON.

Comment: Done but now receiving this error when publishing Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND esker_bot-dev.scm.azurewebsites.net    Esker_Bot is my web app name

Comment: Are you getting any link just below that to provide IP Access?